# Getting difference of a column from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data that is similar to this table below

| id | session_id | user_id | action | log_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | join | 1642645048 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | left | 1642645048 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | join | 1642645552 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | left | 1642646072 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | join | 1642646632 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | left | 1642646736 |
| 7 | 1 | 5 | join | 1642647083 |
| 8 | 1 | 5 | join | 1642649879 |
| 9 | 1 | 5 | left | 1642649951 |
| 10 | 1 | 5 | join | 1642650112 |
| 11 | 1 | 5 | join | 1642650159 |
| 12 | 1 | 5 | join | 1642651005 |

log_time is saved as a unix time

**Question:** Is it possible to retrieve the total amount of time that a user was in a session?

So it would do something like `total_participation = ("1st left" - "1st join") + ("2nd left" - "2nd join") + ("3rd left - "3rd join")`

I've already got the difference between **first join** and **last left** time by doing the following query:

```sql
SELECT s1.session_id as 'Id',
       u.name AS 'Participant',
       IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(s2.time_log - s1.time_log), '%Hh %im %ss'), 0) AS 'TotalParticipation'
FROM tblSessionLog AS s1
LEFT JOIN tblSessionLog AS s2 ON (
    s2.id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM tblSessionLog
        WHERE action = 'left'
            AND user_id = s1.user_id
            AND id > s1.id
        ORDER BY time_log DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
)
LEFT JOIN tblUser AS u ON u.id = s1.user_id -- used only to get participant name
WHERE s1.action = 'join'
GROUP BY s1.session_id, s1.user_id
ORDER BY s1.session_id, s1.user_id;
```

But I can't seem to get how to remove the time in between the participant have left and join backed again. Or is that not possible on SQL and should be handled on backend code?

Not exactly a copy but more or less, the actual data is like this sample SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8f6c/1/0

**Update:**

@Akina's [**solution**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f59aef6c450e23cb218a8fd016201f0) work well when the data is consistent which is very much appreciated but I found out it will not be suitable on my case as there are instances where it is possible to have more than one `join` action before having `left` action, as well as no `left` action after `join` action. I updated the example table above to further show the actual data. Updated the sample fiddle as well.

Any leads will be really appreciated. And apologies as for some reason I need to do this on MySQL without the help of backend code. Thanks!

Comment: With others SQL technologies, you can use PL/SQL, which gives you access to a programming language, meaning that you could store a program with a for loop in your database and call that program as a request. MySQL is limited on that matter, though.

Comment: Hi @SteeveDroz, thanks but I'm a little confused. So you mean, it's not possible or it may be really complicated to achieve the goal by just using MySQL?

Comment: What is MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check. Is it correct to assume that every `join` will always have a `left` afterwards? Is there a possibility that a user have `join` in between a set of `join` & `left` yet (overlapping)? And is it possible that the user `join` but never `left`?

Comment: If your data is correct and consistent then `total_participation = SUM(CASE WHEN action='left')-SUM(CASE WHEN action='join')`.

Comment: @FanoFN Hi, the version says **10.4.21-MariaDB**, Actually those cases are possible, and I'm trying to do it one at a time, like for every `join` there is always a `left`. But yes, it does happen that there is `join` in between `join` and `left` and also possible to have `join` but never `left`. If that makes it easier to do all at once rather than by cases, then I'd appreciate you sharing any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Akina, assuming that the data is correct and consistent, how do I actually put that solution into a query? Any enlightenment is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Provide your sample data as online fiddle or as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Provide desired output for this data.

Comment: Hi @Akina, added sample fiddle on the question. Thank you for taking time!

Comment: How about we pair them up anyhow? Regardless of there's any overlapping `join` or there's no `left`; if the next data after `join` is another (or more) `join`, we just pair the next `left` we've found with the first `join` that were not followed with a `left`?

Comment: @FanoFN Yep, I'm kind of thinking to skip other `join` until another `left` is found, or if no `left` is available, I'll just set the last difference = 0. E.g. `1st left - 1st join = 20m, 2nd join with no left = 0. Then time_participated = 20m`. Will that be easy to query or is that even possible to do on a single table? Thanks for taking time as well!

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f59aef6c450e23cb218a8fd016201f0

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Akina.  Very much appreciated. Although maybe you can help me with other cases. Updated the question above

Comment: I do not see a problem. Firstly decide what you should do with inconsistent data. For example, there are 2 adjacent rows with 'join' - what of them should be removed from the analysis? and the same for two adjacent 'left', for leading 'left', and for trailing 'join'. And in the most first CTE (add it) simply remove these rows making the rowset consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT user_id, action, time_log,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, action ORDER BY time_log) AS rn
FROM tblSessionLog
WHERE action='join'),
cte2 AS(
SELECT user_id, action, time_log,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, action ORDER BY time_log) AS rn
FROM tblSessionLog
WHERE action='left')
SELECT *,
       cte2.time_log-cte1.time_log
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 
ON cte1.user_id=cte2.user_id
AND cte1.rn=cte2.rn;
```

Which on your current data will return the following results:

| user_id | action | time_log | rn | user_id | action | time_log | rn | cte2.time_log-cte1.time_log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | join | 1642645048 | 1 | 3 | left | 1642645048 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | join | 1642645552 | 2 | 3 | left | 1642646072 | 2 | 520 |
| 3 | join | 1642646632 | 3 | 3 | left | 1642646736 | 3 | 104 |
| 5 | join | 1642647083 | 1 | 5 | left | 1642649951 | 1 | 2868 |
| 5 | join | 1642649879 | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | join | 1642650112 | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | join | 1642650159 | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | join | 1642651005 | 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

With two generated [common table expressions (cte)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/), each result from `cte` assigned with [ROW_NUMBER()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_number/) then `LEFT JOIN` them with matching `user_id` and the generated `ROW_NUMBER()`. As your sample data only have 1 `left` for `user_id=5` then it only paired for the first found `join` for the same `user_id` and returned `NULL` for the rest. If a `left` action was added for `user_id=5` afterwards, it will occupy as the `left` action for the `join` action that is `NULL`. For example, if we add:

```
INSERT INTO tblSessionLog (id, session_id, user_id, action, time_log) 
      VALUES (13, 1, 5, 'left', 1642652005);
INSERT INTO tblSessionLog (id, session_id, user_id, action, time_log) 
      VALUES (14, 1, 5, 'left', 1642652085);
```

then the results will be something like this:

| user_id | action | time_log | rn | user_id | action | time_log | rn | cte2.time_log-cte1.time_log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | join | 1642645048 | 1 | 3 | left | 1642645048 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | join | 1642645552 | 2 | 3 | left | 1642646072 | 2 | 520 |
| 3 | join | 1642646632 | 3 | 3 | left | 1642646736 | 3 | 104 |
| 5 | join | 1642647083 | 1 | 5 | left | 1642649951 | 1 | 2868 |
| 5 | join | 1642649879 | 2 | 5 | left | 1642652005 | 2 | 2126 |
| 5 | join | 1642650112 | 3 | 5 | left | 1642652085 | 3 | 1973 |
| 5 | join | 1642650159 | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | join | 1642651005 | 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

One thing to take note is that the `ROW_NUMBER()` I generated here is order by `time_log` and **not** by `id` (or which data was inserted first). If you wish to pair them by which data comes first, you can simply change the `ORDER BY time_log` to `ORDER BY id` on both of the `ROW_NUMBER()` assignment.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a6a5c962b6adb7113aab13d38931b5c0)